# SQL Server Installation Failing -- Could not load file or assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When running the installer from an elevated prompt, like:
`C:\SQL2012Installer\setup.exe`
I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox,
>   Version=11.0.0.0 ...

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: @influent Server 2012

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/93d4c3d9-6ea0-4ad9-a431-ae108a2f1fb8/sql-express-installation-failure?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Comment: I've gotten similar errors but usually it's been when trying to run the installation using a network share or compressed iso, but doesn't look like that's the case for you.  Did you try rerunning it?